# Verben der Bewegung mit Hilfsverb 'haben' in Perfekt

Tags: grammaticality, perfect-tense

Regel 1: *stellen, legen, setzen, hängen, stecken* sind Bewegungsverben und deswegen nimmt man den Akkusativ, wenn man sie mit den Wechselpräpositionen verwendet.

> Er legt das Buch auf den Tisch.

Regel 2: für Verben der Bewegung verwendet man das Hilfsverb *sein* um das Perfekt zu bilden

> Er ist gelaufen.

Wir betrachten jetzt das folgende Beispiel:

> Er hat das Buch auf den Tisch gelegt.

Warum verwendet man das Hilfsverb *haben*, obwohl *legen* (und andere Verben aus Regel eins) ein Verb der Bewegung ist?

Meine eigene Überlegung ist: *stellen, legen, setzen, hängen, stecken* sind transitive Verben und deswegen verwendet man das Hilfsverb *haben* in Perfekt.

Wenn das der Fall ist, warum wirkt Transitivität stärker als Bewegung?

Comment: Woher kommen denn diese Regeln? Das mit dem Akkusativ und der Bewegung ist ein Ammenmärchen. Der Akkusativ deutet auf Richtungsangaben hin, nicht auf Bewegung.

Comment: Man sollte Hilfsregeln, die Sprachlernern angeboten werden, nicht so ernst nehmen, dass man versucht, Widersprüche zwischen ihnen zu finden.

Comment: Es ist offensichtlich, dass Perfekt mit *sein* bei transitiven Verben das Problem hat, dass es mit dem Passiv kollidiert.

Comment: @Olafant Nur weil du davon nicht gehört hast, heißt es nicht, dass es ein Ammenmärchen ist. Für dein Wissen: "Die Verben legen, stellen und setzen beschreiben eine räumliche Bewegung..." [Quelle:DW](https://learngerman.dw.com/de/wechselpräpositionen-3/l-40581904/gr-40585492). Und [deutschplus.net](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Wechselprapositionen)

Comment: @Infinity Die Behauptung, dass Wechselpräpositionen und Akkusativ mit Bewegung zu tun hätten, liest und hört man ständig und sie ist schlicht falsch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verben der Bewegung sind Verben, die ausdrücken können, dass sich der Sprecher bewegt:

> Ich gehe.
> Ich fahre.
> Ich schwimme.
> Ich fliege.

Konkreter: Die Verben drücken ohne weitere Hilfsmittel aus, dass das Subjekt sich selbst bewegt.

> Otto geht.
> Jemand fährt.
> Sie schwimmt.
> Die Vögel fliegen.

Das alles sind völlig korrekte vollständige Sätze, die man aber sebstverständlich noch erweitern kann, z.B. mit einem Ziel oder einer Richtung:

> Ich gehe heim.
> Ich fahre zu meiner Tante.
> Ich schwimme über den Teich.
> Ich fliege nach New York.

Diese Verben benötigen kein Objekt, dass den bewegten Gegenstand bezeichnet. Der Verursacher der Bewegung und das was bewegt wird, sind identisch. Eine solche Angabe wäre sogar falsch:

> alles falsch: <del>Ich gehe mich. Ich fahre mich. Ich schwimme mich. Ich fliege mich.</del>

Anders ist das bei diesen Verben:

> Ich trage den Koffer ins Haus.
> Ich gieße etwas Milch in den Kaffee.
> Ich bewege die Datei in das neue Verzeichnis.

Diese Verben benötigen zwingend ein Objekt, das den bewegten Gegenstand bezeichnet, und sehr oft werden sie auch zusammen mit einem Präpositionalobjekt verwendet, welches das Ziel der Bewegung oder eine Richtung bezeichnet. Wenn die Angabe des bewegten Objekts fehlt, ist der Satz falsch:

> falsch: <del>Ich trage.</del>
> falsch: <del>Ich trage ins Haus.</del>

Obwohl diese Verben ausdrücken, dass ein Objekt vom Subjekt bewegt wird, sind das keine Bewegungsverben. Bewegungsverben drücken immer aus, dass das Subjekt sich selbst bewegt.

Verben, die eine Reise in einem Fahrzeug beschreiben, können auf beide Arten verwendet werden:

Verwendung als Bewegungsverb:

> Ich fahre zum Arzt. Ich bin zum Arzt gefahren.

Nicht als Bewegungsverb verwendet:

> Ich fahre meine Frau zum Arzt. Ich <del>*bin*</del> **habe** meine Frau zum Arzt gefahren.

Die Verben *legen, setzen* und *stellen* sind ebenfalls keine Bewegungsverben. Wenn man angeben will, dass das Subjekt sich selbst bewegt, muss man dazu ein Reflexivpronomen als Objekt verwenden:

> Ich lege mich ins Bett.
> Ich setze mich aufs Sofa.
> Ich stelle mich vor den Spiegel.

Comment: Wenn man deine Definition von Bewegungsverben - Bewegungsverben drücken immer aus, dass das Subjekt sich selbst bewegt - annimmt, ist es verständlich, warum man das Perfekt von *stellen, legen, setzen, hängen, stecken* nicht mit *sein* bildet. Aber genau da bei der Definition von Bewegungsverben taucht Uneinigkeit auf. Denn es gibt [Quellen](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Besonderheiten_transitive_intransitive_Verben), die eine lockere Definition von Bewegungsverben haben und diese Verben auch als "Verben der Bewegung" bezeichnen.

Comment: @Infinity: Die Verben auf der von dir verlinkten Seite sind Richtungs- und Positionsverben. Das steht auch richtig in der großen Überschrift. Die Spaltenüberschriften *"Verben der Bewegung"* und *"Verben der nicht-Bewegung"* (was in korrektem Deutsch eigentlich *"Verben der Nichtbewegung"* heißen müsste) sind keine Definitionen, und sind nur innerhalb des Kontexts von Richtungs- und Positionsverben gemeint.

Answer (score 0):

Aus Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfekt_im_Deutschen#Geschichte

> In historischer Sicht steht die Ausbreitung und Ausbildung des
> deutschen Perfekts im 14. und 15. Jahrhundert im Zusammenhang mit dem
> Rückgang der finiten Form mit präfigiertem ge- und der aspektuellen
> Opposition (vgl. lexikalisiert noch heute frieren versus gefrieren).
> **„Sein“ stand zunächst bei intransitiven Verben perfekter Aktionsart
> und diente ursprünglich zur präsentischen Bezeichnung des Resultats
> eines vergangenen Vorgangs**, etwa er ist gefallen = ‘er liegt am
> Boden’, oder er ist gefahren = ‘er ist da’. Im Gegensatz hierzu hatte
> das Perfekt mit „haben“ bei transitiven Verben ursprünglich eine
> passive Bedeutung, etwa ich habe das Buch gefunden = ‘ich habe das
> Buch als ein gefundenes’. Im Laufe der Zeit wurden diese
> Konstruktionen zunehmend zeitlich gedeutet und die Verwendung der
> beiden Hilfswörter lexikalisiert, wobei eine gewisse Verschiebung von
> „haben“ zu „sein“ stattfand.

Comment: Inwiefern beantwortet das die Frage?